# Converting from std::vector<unsigned char> to wstring of different endianness

Tags: c++, endianness

How can I convert an `std::vector<unsigned char>` to a `std::wstring` ?

Also the data in the vector is in little-endian order order meaning

I transmit this:

```
0xBE 0xEF 0xBE 0xEF 0xBE 0xEF 0xBE 0xEF
```

And I receive this which is stored in my vector

```
0xEF 0xBE 0xEF 0xBE 0xEF 0xBE 0xEF 0xBE
```

I somehow have to revert it back to it's original form and convert it into an `std::wstring`. How can I do that? ( The machine this code runs on is always x86 or x64)

Answer (score 1):

Without the reordering, you can use a `std::wstringstream` for that:

```
std::vector<unsigned char> vec{'B','E',' ','E','F',' ','B','E',' ','E','F',' ','B','E',' ','E','F',' ','B','E',' ','E','F'};
std::wstringstream ss;
for(auto v : vec)
{
    ss<<v;
}
std::wstring w = ss.str();
```

The reordering itself, however, I didn't understand, so incorporate it by yourself by traversing the vector in the correct way.